# Hiding Table Rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to hide a bunch of table rows using javascript.
I think i've got most of the code correct, I just don't know why it isn't running the hide.

Any help is appreciated.

The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideButton()
    {
    $("#showHideButton").on("click", function (e) {
    var button = e.target;
    var node = $(button).parent().parent().next();

    while (!node.hasClass("service-header")) {
        if ($(node).is(":visible")) {
            $(node).hide();
        } else {
            $(node).show();
        }
        node = node.next();
    }
    })}
    </script>
```

The HTML is:

```
for (loopHere) 
{
    echo "<tr class='service-header'><th>InfoHere</th><th>" . InfoHere . "<button style='float:right' type='button' id='showHideButton' class='btn btn-default' onclick='hideButton()'><span class='dashicons dashicons-arrow-down-alt2'></span></button></th></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>More Stuff</td></tr>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>More Stuff</td></tr>";
}
loop
```

I've got no idea why it won't hide the rows on the click, I have tested it on a table with multiple rows that have the class service-header, but haven't had any luck.

Comment: `e` is not defined at event handler `hideButton()`. You are also attaching a new `click` event at each click of element. What is purpose of `while` loop?

Comment: Post the HTML too..also, either define the function for click or use on event handlers but not both

Comment: can you html mark up as well

Comment: @guest271314 it's a table with headers for certain sections then information under that section, then another header, so i want to be able to hide the "tr's" that aren't don't have the "service-header" class.
The table is autoconstructing so I have multiple buttons that need to hide the information under them.

Are you saying I only need to change hideButton() to hideButton(e) or do I need to change the html in the onclick='hideButton()' part also?

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 sorry had to shorten the code i was over the wordcount.

Comment: @WellConnectedIT update the OP not put code in comment

Comment: Edit the question instead of putting code into the comment

Comment: ***ID should be unique*** .. `use class then use this context`

Comment: @guradio thanks for the advice.

Can you show how you'd do it. I'm not as fluent in javascript as I'd like to be.

Comment: add rendered html.. il add a demo.. i will add event handler for that

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code as per your requirement I have created below example.Hopefully it will solve your problem

```js
$(document).on("click", ".showHideButton",function () {
debugger;
//console.log("this="+this+" && $(this)="+$(this));
if($(this).parent().parent().hasClass("service-header") && $(this).parent().parent().is(":visible")){
     $(this).parent().parent().hide();
     }
     else{
       $(this).parent().parent().show();
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="service-header">
      <td>1 (has class)</td>
      <td>1 (has class)</td>
      <td><button  type='button'  class='showHideButton btn btn-default'>show/hide</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><button  type='button'  class='showHideButton btn btn-default'>show/hide</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="service-header">
      <td>3 (has class)</td>
      <td>3 (has class)</td>
      <td><button  type='button'  class='showHideButton btn btn-default'>show/hide</button></td>
       <tr class="service-header">
      <td>4 (has class)</td>
      <td>4 (has class)</td>
      <td><button  type='button'  class='showHideButton btn btn-default'>show/hide</button></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5 </td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><button  type='button'  class='showHideButton btn btn-default'>show/hide</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestion to make this work.

hideButton() and $("#showHideButton").on("click"...... both are doing the same thing (initializing click function). So i suggest to remove function hideButton(){ } from your code.

Now your id "#showHideButton" must be unique in a single web page.

If it still not works then do check your HTML structure.

Try after these changes. Hope this helps.